# How to rebuild the log file in Python?

Tags: python

Program A by Python:

```
LOG_PATH = fdoc_log + "/store_plus.log"
 FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
 logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_PATH, filemode = 'w', level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)
```

Program B by bash:

```
 mv store_plus.log store_plus.log.bk
```

The Program A will run in the background and don't stop. When 
the Program B delete the file  of store_plus.log, the Program A can't write log as well.
If I want the Program A rebuild the store_plus.log, How to solve it ?
Thank you

PS: the way :

```
 f = open(LOG_PATH, "a")
 f.close()
```

It can't work.

Comment: Wait, why are you deleting the original file? Why not use `cp` rather than `mv`?

Comment: Wouldn't the [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) in logging do what you want ? Let logging take care of moving the log file.

Comment: cp is not atomic. So should mv

Comment: RotatingFileHandler  is a good way. But the company want to manage the log system. So the bash script will be used to manage the Program by C++, Python and so on. Thank you.

Comment: Then perhaps [WatchedFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler) might show the way. Failing that perhaps you could expand your question to detail the usage scenario.

Comment: Hmmm... Why not handle the entire problem in Python, rather than using a bash script?

Comment: Thank you.  WatchedFileHandler  is a  good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way is OK by  WatchedFileHandler :

```
    logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler('a_log')
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example taken from [pymotw-logging](http://blog.doughellmann.com/2007/05/pymotw-logging.html) and all credit to Doug Hellmann.

```
import glob
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = '/tmp/logging_rotatingfile_example.out'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add the log message handler to the logger
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

# Log some messages
for i in range(20):
   my_logger.debug('i = %d' % i)

# See what files are created
logfiles = glob.glob('%s*' % LOG_FILENAME)

for filename in logfiles:
   print filename
```